# Angular 6 : async await some variable got it variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6

Under my **Angular 6** app, I have a variable "permittedPefs" which is getting value after an HTTP call **(asynchronous)**

```
 @Injectable()
 export class FeaturesLoadPermissionsService {
    permittedPefs = [];
    constructor() {       
       this.loadUserPefsService.getUserRolePefs(roleId)
                               .subscribe(
              (returnedListPefs) => {
                this.permittedPefs = returnedListPefs;
              },
              error => {
                console.log(error);
              });
    }
}
```

in another method, I'm using that same variable:**permittedPefs**

But as it's initially empty and it gots its value after such a time, so I need to wait for it to re-use it.

I've tried to use **async-await**, and my purpose is waiting for **permittedPefs** to got a**object value**

```
  async checkPefPresence(pefId) {
    const listPefs = await this.permittedPefs
  }
```

**how to fix it ??**

Comment: instead of subscribing to `getUserRolePefs()` just return the `Observable`. Then in your other method, you can subscribe to `permittedPefs` and continue working.

Comment: move the subscription to ngOninit

Comment: [Don't do asynchronous stuff in your constructor!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24686979/1048572)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As loadUserPefsService.getUserRolePefs method returns Observable you can store it and subscribe to it later when you need it.

```
 @Injectable()
 export class FeaturesLoadPermissionsService {
     permittedPefs = [];
     constructor() {
         this.userRolePefsObservable = this.loadUserPefsService.getUserRolePefs(roleId);
     }
 }

 checkPefPresence(pefId) {
     let listPefs;
     this.userRolePefsObservable.subscribe(
         (returnedListPefs) => {
             listPefs = returnedListPefs;
         },
         error => {
             console.log(error);
         });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a behaviorSubject

```
  @Injectable()
    export class FeaturesLoadPermissionsService {

      permittedPefs: BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

      constructor() {
        this.loadUserPefsService.getUserRolePefs(roleId)
          .subscribe((returnedListPefs) => {
            this.permittedPefs.next(returnedListPefs);
          },
            error => {
              console.log(error);
            });
      }
    }
```

Then where ever you are checking for it(remember to unsubscribe when you are done)

if it has to be async you can do it like below

```
  async checkPefPresence(pefId): Promise {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.featuresLoadPermissionsService.permittedPefs.subscribe(listPefs  => {
          //handle whatever check you want to do here 
          resolve();
      },reject);
    })
```